# How do I put a single csv row into one list with no duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have a csv file with a row that I need to put into a list. An example of the row would be

```
row A
apple
apple
apple
orange
orange
watermelon
```

and i need to read that row into a list without the duplicate names, so it would look like

```
['apple','orange','watermelon']
```

Here is my current code for this problem:

```
import csv
start = open('fruits.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(start)
next(reader, None)
for row in reader:
    fruits = [row[1]]
    print(fruits)
```

My current code just puts each individual line into its own list.

Comment: use set() in place of list if the order doesn't matter.

Comment: You have a column (vertical), not a row (horizontal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you provided, you are creating a new list with a single item every time you loop though the for loop. Instead, you want to maintain a growing list

```
import csv
start = open('data.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(start)
next(reader, None)

fruits = [] #define an empty list
for row in reader:
    fruits.append(row[1]) #add to the list
```

Note that in the data example you provide, there is only one column so it should be `row[0]` instead of `row[1]` if we are strictly using that example

To make the list unique, you can convert it into a set which enforces uniqueness:

```
fruits = set(fruits)
```

If you want it to be converted back into a list, try the following:

```
fruits = list(fruits)
```

Note that this method does not guarantee the order of the list will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

data = 'fruits.csv'

fruits = []

# read csv, append unique items to list
with open(data, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] not in fruits: 
            fruits.append(row[0])

# output: ['row A', 'apple', 'orange', 'watermelon']
print(fruits_in)
```

Comment: Why do you need two loops? Just append the _element_ instead of the _entire row_ in the first loop?